# Does toPromise() unsubscribe from the Observable?

Tags: rxjs

I have not been able to find any normative text to answer this question.  I have been using this code pattern (this is in TypeScript in an Angular application):

```js
observeSomethingFun$: Observable<Fun>;
    ...
async loadsOfFun() {
  const fun = await this.observeSomethingFun$.toPromise();
    // I now have fun
}
```

In general, Observables need to be unsubscribed from.  This happens automatically when the Angular `async` pipe is used but what happens in this case?   Does `toPromise` unsubscribe after emitting one value?

If not, how do I unsubscribe manually?

**Update:**

It turns out @Will Taylor's answer below is correct but my question needs some clarification.

In my case the Observable emits a never-ending stream, unlike for example Angular's **HttpClient** Observables that complete after emitting one value.  So
in my case I would never get past the `await` statement according to Taylor's answer.

RxJS makes this easy to fix.  The correct statement turns out to be:

```
const fun = await this.observeSomethingFun$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
```

The RxJS `first` operator will receive the first value and unsubscribe from the source Observable.  it will then send out that value to the `toPromise` operator
and then complete.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @Asadefa As it says: Typescript.  But it might as well be just Javascript

Comment: Ok then so it is Typescript. I don't know Typescript so sorry I can't help.

Comment: The promise resolves when the source observable completes or errors - in which case, automatic unsubscription occurs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No need to unsubscribe.**

Which is convenient, as there is no way to unsubscribe from a promise.

- If the Observable completes - the promise will `resolve` with the last value emitted and all subscribers will automatically be unsubscribed at this point.
- If the Observable errors - the promise will `reject` and all subscribers will automatically be unsubscribed at this point.

However, there are a couple of edge cases with `toPromise` in which the behavior is not completely clear from [the docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md).

1. If the Observable emits one or more values but does not complete or error, the promise will neither resolve or reject. In this case, the promise would hang around in memory, which is worth considering when working with `toPromise`.
2. If the Observable completes but does not emit a value, the promise will `resolve` with `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thank you for this question and answer, I **wrongly assumed** `toPromise()` knew what it was doing in all scenarios and would unsubscribe when that observable completes (even if it is an observable stream)

So I will just say that it doesn't hurt to pipe all of your observables before using `.toPromise()`

I just went through a big ordeal of stepping through our app for memory leaks and found the above answer by Will to be good. The elaboration on the actual question was exactly the same issue I was running into.

We are stepping through each observable in the app right now and we use either

`pipe(take(1))` which is equivalent to `pipe(first())`.

or we use `pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))` where `this.destroyed.next(true)` is called when we destroy our particular component or service.

We use `take()` to keep our verbiage consistent so we can search for take or takeUntil across various components.

Long story short, yeah you might take a very slight performance hit piping your observables at each instance, but I highly recommend doing so in order to prevent any unwanted app-wide memory leak hunts. Then maybe if you have the time you can step through each one and see where `.toPromise()` actually unsubscribes correctly for you.