# Using RxJs would you unsubscribe when using from(myPromise)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I use the `async` pipe in Angular, or `takeUntil(...)` on components using:

```js
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

}
```

But, I've always wondered what I need to do when using `from(myPromise)`.  Promises only provide a single result, but I've converted it to an observable so it feels like if I make an equivalent method that provides an observable instead that I should be using `take(1)` or unsubscribing depending on use since I don't always subscribe directly and instead use it in an `exhaustMap(() => this.hasTokenExpired$()`.

```js
  public async hasTokenExpired(): Promise<boolean> {
    const token = await this.getToken();

    if (token) {
      return this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    return true;
  }

  // Observable equivalent method:
  public hasTokenExpired$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(this.hasTokenExpired()); // Could pipe `take(1)` permanently
  }
```

Should I being using `take(1)` on `from(myPromise)`? It's been on my mind for awhile in case this causes a memory leak, but I can't find an article confirming that I should.

Also, if there's a better way to make these kinds of observable equivalent methods I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: You don't need to use `take(1)`, `from()` will emit `complete` notification right after the Promise resolves. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/from.ts#L191-L205

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need to use `take` in this case, as an Observable created from a Promise will only ever either:

- Emit 1 value and complete if the Promise resolves.
- Error if the Promise rejects.

This answer may be helpful to read too: [Does toPromise() unsubscribe from the Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402377/does-topromise-unsubscribe-from-the-observable/59406441#59406441)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and especially thanks for the link